# How to insert into netezza table from SSIS with sequence value

Tags: sql, database, netezza, ssis-2012

I am trying to do a basic dataflow task in SSIS2012 where the destination is a Netezza table. I have a column that I named "Transaction_ID" that I am planning to use as a primary key and I have a sequence ready to populate it (Seq_Transaction_ID). However, I am not sure how exactly to assign the sequence.

For instance I tried making the table and assigning the column to a default of the next value for the sequence and got an error "you can only use a next value function within a target list". I'm also not sure how I would get the sequence into SSIS either.

Any ideas?

Thank you,

Comment: What is the source RDBMS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Next value function error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829458/next-value-function-error)